# Symfony Twig Templates in Netbeans

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans, twig

I am new to Symfony and am trying to create a Twig template in NetBeans. However, by default NetBeans doesn't support the file extension `.twig`. I tried to google but couldn't find any answer. I saw some Twig NetNeans plugins in my Google search result but they didn't say whether they support the `.twig` file extension so I decided not to download them.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: switch over to phpStorm and use the plugin Symfony2 :)

Comment: @Baig Is there no solution/plugin for netbeans?

Comment: I used to use netbeans a long time ago and back then i was not working with Symfony so at present i have no idea if they have any plugin. Reason I am recommending phpStorm is because their IDE is alot better that netbeans in my opinion and they have a plugin specially for Symfony

Answer (score 1):

I use NetBeans 8.0.2 and I can edit Twig files correctly using the "Twig Templates" plugin. It's a core plugin, in the "PHP" category. You can enable it via Tools -> Plugins.

Note: since it's a a core plugin, you don't find it in "Available Plugins", but in "Installed Plugins". Being a core plugin, it's already installed, you probably only have to "Activate" it.

Comment: @Francescon Abeni Can you tell me the exact name of the plugin. I go to the Tools->Plugins. I then click on the 'Available Plugins' tab but i don't see any twig template plugin in the list